# Подгрузка списка RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

В моем APi есть параметр `offset`, который отвечает за сдвиг элементов от начальной точки. Так же есть параметр `limit`, который отвечает за получаемую порцию данных. То есть при первоначальном запросе эти параметры выглядят так `limit=20&offset=0`. Мне нужно при скроллинге моего списка добавлять +20 к `offset` каждый раз, когда прокрутка достигнет последнего элемента. Находил множество вопросов по пагинации с ответами, но не смог прикрутить к моему проекту

Метод, который отвечает за погрузку

```
Call<MainModel> loadMore(
            @Query("offset") int limit
    );
```

Так как мне вызвать этот метод и где его вызывать? В активити?

Вот listenter (не заполнен до конца)

```
public class PaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    int visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, firstVisiblePosition;

    public PaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.linearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    }
}
```

ListCatalogActivity

```
public class ListCatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ListCatalog {
    private ListCatalogPresenter presenter;
    private Toolbar toolbarCatalogList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerUpper, recyclerMain;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private String sortBy, sortType;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
    private CatalogListAdapter catalogListAdapter;
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_catalog);

        initView();

        //Получаю список категорий
        presenter = new ListCatalogPresenter();
        presenter.attachView(this);
        presenter.getCategories();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    //Получаю список товаров
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        switch (position) {
            //Список товаров с сортировкой от дешевых к дорогим
            case 0:
                sortBy = "price";
                sortType = "asc";
                presenter.getList(sortBy, sortType);
                break;

            //Список товаров с сортировкой от дорогих к дешевым
            case 1:
                sortBy = "price";
                sortType = "desc";
                presenter.getList(sortBy, sortType);
                break;

            //Список товаров с сортировкой по популярности
            case 2:
                sortBy = "rating";
                sortType = "desc";
                presenter.getList(sortBy, sortType);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

    @Override
    public void getCategories(MainModel mainModel) {
        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(ListCatalogActivity.this, mainModel);
        recyclerUpper.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void getList(MainModel mainModel, String sortBy, String sortType) {
        catalogListAdapter = new CatalogListAdapter(ListCatalogActivity.this, mainModel);
        recyclerMain.setAdapter(catalogListAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCompositeDisposable(CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
        this.compositeDisposable = compositeDisposable;
        presenter.deleteCompositeDisposable(compositeDisposable);
    }


    @Override
    public void showProgress(boolean visibility) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(visibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    private void initView() {
        //Toolbar
        toolbarCatalogList = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_catalog);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarCatalogList);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //ProgressBar
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        //Верхний горизонтальный recycler
        recyclerUpper = findViewById(R.id.recycler_upper);
        recyclerUpper.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        //Основной вертикальный recycler
        recyclerMain = findViewById(R.id.recycler_main);
        recyclerMain.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

        //Выпадающее меню
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(2);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void closeListCatalogActivity(View view){
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google выпустила очень неплохой инструмент - [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging).
Ставите в зависимости вот такую штуку:

```
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0"
```

Создаете адаптер аналогично такому:

```
class EmployeeAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Employee, EmployeeViewHolder> {
 
   protected EmployeeAdapter(DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Employee> diffUtilCallback) {
       super(diffUtilCallback);
   }
 
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public EmployeeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.employee, parent, false);
       EmployeeViewHolder holder = new EmployeeViewHolder(view);
       return holder;
   }
 
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmployeeViewHolder holder, int position) {
       holder.bind(getItem(position));
   }
 
}
```

После чего создаете PagedList с помощью такого билдера:

```
PagedList<Employee> pagedList = new PagedList.Builder<>(dataSource, config)
       .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
       .setMainThreadExecutor(new MainThreadExecutor())
       .build();
```

Вам так же нужно создать DataSource. DataSource - это посредник между PagedList и Storage.

```
class MyPositionalDataSource extends PositionalDataSource<Employee> {
 
    private final EmployeeStorage employeeStorage;
 
    public MyPositionalDataSource(EmployeeStorage employeeStorage) {
        this.employeeStorage = employeeStorage;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Employee> callback) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadInitial, requestedStartPosition = " + params.requestedStartPosition +
                ", requestedLoadSize = " + params.requestedLoadSize);
        List<Employee> result = employeeStorage.getData(params.requestedStartPosition, params.requestedLoadSize);
        callback.onResult(result, 0);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void loadRange(@NonNull LoadRangeParams params, @NonNull LoadRangeCallback<Employee> callback) {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadRange, startPosition = " + params.startPosition + ", loadSize = " + params.loadSize);
        List<Employee> result = employeeStorage.getData(params.startPosition, params.loadSize);
        callback.onResult(result);
    }
 
}
```

И собственно вот так собираете всю эту схему:

```
// DataSource
MyPositionalDataSource dataSource = new MyPositionalDataSource(new EmployeeStorage());
 
 
// PagedList
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPageSize(10)
        .build();
 
PagedList<Employee> pagedList = new PagedList.Builder<>(dataSource, config)
        .setMainThreadExecutor(new MainThreadExecutor())
        .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        .build();
 
 
// Adapter
adapter = new EmployeeAdapter(diffUtilCallback);
adapter.submitList(pagedList);
 
 
// RecyclerView
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/542-urok-14-paging-library-chast-1.html) есть прям целая серия уроков по Paging Library. Рекомендую ознакомиться.

Comment: Данный адаптер заменяется моим или добавляется? За ссылку спасибо, ознакомлюсь и отпишусь

Comment: Ну да. Этот адаптер надо написать вместо вашего. Он похож, там проблем переписать быть не должно

Answer (score 0):

Я решил это следующим образом

В интерфейс добавил отдельный метод, который отвечает только за подгрузку

```
Single<MainModel> loadMore(
            @Query("limit") int limit
    );
```

И в активити при скроллинге до последнего элемента вызываю этот метод

```
recyclerMain.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                int visibleItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int pastVisibleItems = gridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (pastVisibleItems + totalItemCount >= visibleItemCount){
                    int limit = +20;
                    presenter.loadMore(limit);
                }
            }
        });
```